# typo3 shared-content-variables link with local-link

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have a typo3-installation with several domains as well as some shared content, using Realurl to generate «speaking»-Links.

Now, I declared some shared content variables to generate links.

Element type is set to Link, the link itself is just the id of the target-page.
This works - unless I add an anchor reference to the link.

-> 490#localAnchor

Without the #, Realurl generates the appropriate link (something like «www.mypage.com/mygreatcontent/mygreatpage»).

With the #, Realurl fails and I end up with something like «www.mypage.com/490#localAnchor», instead of «www.mypage.com/mygreatcontent/mygreatpage#localAnchor».

I found the hint that I should set `config.prefixLocalAnchor = all` in the config-file - but this doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share some more of your configuration and code where the link is generated. Is `config.typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains = 1` set?

Comment: The link is generated through typo3 with a shared content variable. All I can set there is an element-type and the link (which - usually - is just the number of the page the link points to). I tried to set the config-variable you mention, but that didn't help.